# W/System.err: StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down

Tags: android

Ao abrir repetidas vezes uma Activity ocorre o seguinte erro:

> ```
> E/StrictMode: class br.com.teccity.cardapiosduchef.empresa.EmpresaActivity; instances=2; limit=1
>               android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class br.com.teccity.cardapiosduchef.empresa.EmpresaActivity; instances=2; limit=1
>                   at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
> W/System.err: StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.
> ```

Procurando uma solução pelos fóruns da internet, achei o seguinte exemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectCustomSlowCalls() // API level 11, to use with StrictMode.noteSlowCode
            .detectDiskReads()
            .detectDiskWrites()
            .detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyFlashScreen() // API level 11
            .build());

    try {
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                .detectLeakedClosableObjects() // API level 11
                .setClassInstanceLimit(Class.forName("com.apress.proandroid.SomeClass"), 100)
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Mas também não resolveu o problema.

Comment: Tudo indica que tem um vazamento de memória(*memory leak*) provocado por essa Activity.

Comment: Saberia me dizer como posso identificar qual seria este vazamento seria?

Comment: Terá de adicionar à pergunta o código da Activity.